# Привязать координаты к матрице и кликать

Tags: python, матрицы, координаты

Есть массив с координатами.

```
class Cords:
    cord11 = (1190, 135)
    cord12 = (1352, 135)
    cord13 = (1514, 135)
    cord14 = (1676, 135)
    cord21 = (1199, 297)
    cord22 = (1352, 297)
    cord23 = (1514, 297)
    cord24 = (1676, 297)
    cord31 = (1190, 459)
    cord32 = (1352, 459)
    cord33 = (1514, 459)
    cord34 = (1676, 459)
    cord41 = (1190, 621)
    cord42 = (1352, 621)
    cord43 = (1514, 621)
    cord44 = (1676, 621)
    cord51 = (1190, 783)
    cord52 = (1352, 783)
    cord53 = (1514, 783)
    cord54 = (1676, 783)
    cord61 = (1190, 945)
    cord62 = (1352, 945)
    cord63 = (1514, 945)
    cord64 = (1676, 945)
```

Есть матрица со значениями :

```
[[ 33   0  33 229]
 [233 109 255 109]
 [ 60  72  60  59]
 [108   0 255  24]
 [ 59 229  77 108]
 [ 72  24  77 233]]
```

И там и там 24 элемента.
В матрице 12 пар. Тоесть каждому элементу есть пара.

Нужно как-то привязать координаты к матрице, и кликать мышью по совпадающим значениям.

К примеру в данной матрице 33 должно быть cord11, следующее 33 cor13.

А потом последовательно кликнуть по этим двум координатам.

Как кликать я знаю, не понятно как именно привязать координаты к каждому элементу и найти одинаковые элементы в матрице.

Comment: нужно превратить cordxx в индексированную структуру, например - в список

Comment: Превратил, что с ним теперь делать? `cordArray = [cord11, cord12, cord13, cord14,
                 cord21, cord22, cord23, cord24,
                 cord31, cord32, cord33, cord34,
                 cord41, cord42, cord43, cord44,
                 cord51, cord52, cord53, cord54,
                 cord61, cord62, cord63, cord64]`

Comment: @SuddenDumb наверное можно создать словарь и заполнить его парами ключ-значение(элемент-координата)

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, я начал правильно?  `dcord = {cord11: matrix[0], cord12: matrix[1], cord13: matrix[2]}`

Comment: @SuddenDumb  если у вас i-ый элемент матрицы соответсвует i-ому элементу координат то можно сделать так `my_dict ={}

for i in range(len(my_list)):
        my_dict[i] = cordArray[i]`

Comment: Поздно)  Уже напечатал это : `dcord = {cord11: matrix[0], cord12: matrix[1], cord13: matrix[2], cord14: matrix[3],
             cord21: matrix[4], cord22: matrix[5], cord23: matrix[6], cord24: matrix[7],
             cord31: matrix[8], cord32: matrix[9], cord33: matrix[10], cord34: matrix[11],
             cord41: matrix[12], cord42: matrix[13], cord43: matrix[14], cord44: matrix[15],
             cord51: matrix[16], cord52: matrix[17], cord53: matrix[18], cord54: matrix[19],
             cord61: matrix[20], cord62: matrix[21], cord63: matrix[22], cord64: matrix[23]}`

Comment: Только что теперь с этим делать, первый раз работаю со словарями

Comment: Как этот словарь поможет мне кликать на парные элементы здесь : `[[ 33   0  33 229]
 [233 109 255 109]
 [ 60  72  60  59]
 [108   0 255  24]
 [ 59 229  77 108]
 [ 72  24  77 233]]`

Comment: Почему бы в матрице не хранить пары изначально?

Comment: Ну, нужно будет кликать на одинаковые значения в матрице

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать если в матрице будут только значения,а если еще и координаты....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет привязки - самый простой вариант :

```
coords = [
          [(1190, 135), (1352, 135), (1514, 135), (1676, 135)],
          [(1199, 297), (1352, 297), (1514, 297), (1676, 297)],
          [(1190, 459), (1352, 459), (1514, 459), (1676, 459)],
          [(1190, 621), (1352, 621), (1514, 621), (1676, 621)],
          [(1190, 783), (1352, 783), (1514, 783), (1676, 783)],
          [(1190, 945), (1352, 945), (1514, 945), (1676, 945)]
]

matrix = [
         [33, 0, 33, 229],
         [233, 109, 255, 109],
         [60, 72, 60, 59],
         [108, 0, 255, 24],
         [59, 229, 77, 108],
         [72, 24, 77, 233]
]

# привязка
matrix_coords = {coords[i][j] : matrix[i][j] for i in range(6) for j in range(4)}
```

То есть мы создаем два списка и их связываем в словаре <координита> : <значение>. Связываем симметрично.
Насчет поиска одинаковых, не совсем понимаю, в каком виде вам их нужно увидеть. Но в целом, вариант: поочередно проверить каждый элемент на равенство с любым другим из матрицы. Да, выглядет так себе, но по логике, должно работать.

Comment: В этом деле, очень важна скорость, нужно постараться найти максимально быстрый способ

Comment: А пока попробую ваш метод

Comment: Теперь нужно сделать сравнение каждого элемента с каждым элементом, именно по значению, не трогая координаты, и если совпадают значения,кликнуть по этим координатам с помощью `pyautogui.click(cord)`

Comment: Можно понятнее? У вас тут вообще у всех чисел есть пара такого же значения. То есть, если нашелся такой же по значению, то делается клик сначала по первому, а потом по второму? Например, 33, спустя одно значения перебора нашлось снова 33, делается клик сначала по координатам (1190, 135), затем по (1514, 135)?

Comment: У вас тут вообще у всех чисел есть пара такого же значения. Так я же написал "И там и там 24 элемента. В матрице 12 пар. Тоесть каждому элементу есть пара."

Comment: Нет, не обязательно сперва по первому, потом по второму, можно наоборот, главное что-бы оба клика были по одинаковым значениям, то есть по координатам одинаковых значений

Comment: Тут человек поделился такой идеей : " словарь такого вида :`{ значение: [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...]}`"

Comment: То есть создать словарь который хранит значение и ЧЕТЫРЕ координаты

Comment: так как у каждого значения есть пара, получается что можно просто обьединить два одинаковых значения в одно, но с четырями координатами ( имеется ввиду "значение: (x1,y1),(x2,y2)") Так было бы намного удобнее в дальнейшем кликать по координатам

Comment: Но как создать такой словарь, использую матрицу и список координат, я не знаю.   Есть варианты?